# Import in Mathematica does not work

Tags: import, finite-element-method, mesh, stl-format

I want to import STL files as boundary element mesh.

```
furnitureBmesh =  Import["C:\\Users\\sagalab\\Documents\\WolframMathematica\\sample2.stl", "ElementMesh"];
```

The error I am getting is

```
Import::noelem The Import element "ElementMesh" is not present when importing as STL.
```

I am referring to the following site

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/Acoustics/ModelCollection/RoomEigenfrequencies.html.ja

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! It will be helpful if you: (1) Include your file (`sample2.stl`) into the question (you will have to upload it somewhere, then give the link). (2) Explain how you generated that file (which software you used). (3) Let us know which version of Mathematica you are using.

Comment: (1)https://kwanseio365-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/dtd68073_nuc_kwansei_ac_jp/Eduv7UKoG31FtXz_MjCexvMBwKRm9PtHBl08AoF-6pUrxw?e=2ea9qV

Comment: (2)Created with Blender　(3)Version 13.3.1 for Microsoft Windows(64-bit)

Comment: I think you should report this to WRI.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a workaround:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
mr = Import["file.stl"];
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[mr];
```